# Structure array or cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, data-structures

I can define my data structure by two different ways:

Number 1:

```
for i = 1:3, matrix.a{1,i} = rand(1,2000000); end
for i = 1:3, matrix.a{2,i} = rand(1,2000000); end
for i = 1:3, matrix.g{2,i} = rand(1); end
for i = 1:3, matrix.g{1,i} = rand(1); end
```

Number 2:

```
for i = 1:3, matrix2(1,i).a = rand(1,2000000); end
for i = 1:3, matrix2(2,i).a = rand(1,2000000); end
for i = 1:3, matrix2(1,i).g = rand(1); end
for i = 1:3, matrix2(2,i).g = rand(1); end
```

Is one of them a much more efficient way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no large difference, both contain 6 matrices with 2 000 000 elements, this is the important part and unchanged. You can compare execution time of the code (`tic` `toc`) and memory (`whos`) with this single code line `x=rand(6,2000001)` which obviously generates and stores the required amount of random numbers in the most efficient way. There is no significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

Check `whos matrix matrix2`, that will show you the memory usage of both alternatives.

Without spending too much thought it should be pretty similar - it certainly is compared to the memory you need for the random numbers.